# How can I send HTTP Basic Authentication headers in RSelenium?

Tags: r, selenium

I am trying to access [this](https://www.freddiemac.com/sec_products_data/) website using RSelenium

```
wd <- getwd()
eCaps <- list(
        chromeOptions = 
                list(prefs = list(
                        "profile.default_content_settings.popups" = 0L,
                        "download.prompt_for_download" = FALSE,
                        "download.default_directory" = wd
                )
                )
)

rD <- rsDriver(extraCapabilities = eCaps)
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate("https://username:password@urlhere/")
```

It seems to be not working. I need to access the website in R, because rest of my script is written in R.

Comment: @DebanjanB I would like to access in R, because rest of the code that I wrote is written in R and the python code is not working for the website that I have provided.

Comment: Factually, you simply need to follow the signature just like `get("http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")` in your line of code when you invoke `navigate("https://username:password@urlhere/")`. Your actual _URL_ could have helped me to construct an answer for you.

Comment: I have provided the link to the website when you click the "this" text.

Comment: Can I have a demo set of credentials?

Comment: Is there any other means to communicate with you, I cannot put them here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164431/discussion-between-durga-gaddam-and-debanjanb).